# Opening pdf links in new window with jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is probably VERY simple and silly, but I am trying to use jQuery to open all pdf's in new windows.  I used the code below and get this error:

> uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href$=.pdf]

I am being a nitwit, I am sure, any help would be appreciated.

Note: I subbed in jQuery for $ because I am using Wordpress.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
jQuery("a[href$=.pdf]").click(function() {
window.open(this.href);
}); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: you don't need to sub in jQuery for $, you can just encapsulate, since jQuery passes itself to the arguments for .ready: `jQuery(function($) { $('a[...]')... });`

Comment: Additionally he was missing a `.preventDefault()` call - the link would have opened twice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a[href$=".pdf"]').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: @user10210 - Note the inner quotes around `.pdf`.  That is actually what was wrong with your code, but I agree that this is a more elegant solution to your problem.  (Using single quotes, of course, in your example above.)

Comment: Thank you both for the patience, clarification and answers!